# How do I remove [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting this console error when I scroll carousel left or right. I tried adding `{passive: false}` as third argument to scroll event below but it gives me a new error after that which is a.apply is not a function:

```js
var el = $('.touchcarousel .touchcarousel-wrapper');
var lastX = el.scrollLeft();
var scrollableWidth = $(el)[0].scrollWidth - window.innerWidth;
var scrollableItemWidth = Math.floor(scrollableWidth / itemCount);
var array = [];

for (var i = scrollableItemWidth; i <= scrollableWidth; i += scrollableItemWidth) 
{
    array.push(i);
}

$(el).on('scroll', function (e) {
    var currX = el.scrollLeft();

    array.each(function (itemLength) {
        var x = (currX > lastX && currX === itemLength) ? fireGaEvent('User clicked/swipe right') : ((currX < lastX && currX === itemLength) ? fireGaEvent('User clicked/swipe left') : 'none');
    });

    lastX = currX;
});
```

Could you help?

The default inside the passive event listener cannot be avoided due to passive handling of the target. You can check [this link](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080).

Comment: Maybe giving the console output details in the question will help. It's hard to understand where the error is getting thrown.

Comment: I've added the console output but I have mentioned it in the title.

Comment: Does this answer help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68344657/skrollr-mobile-broken-unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener

Comment: I am not using Skrollr library or any library for that matter and have tried css solution but I can only write in ES5. Everything is native. I am grabbing the selector and just scrolling images left and right

Comment: I am reading the .on documentation on JQuery's site. https://api.jquery.com/on/
It says that returning false will call .preventDefault. Maybe no return statement is being coerced to false. What happens if you add a 'return true;' to your handler function.

Comment: @joshvito - So I just add return true inside the event handler function?

Comment: sure, give it a try. add return true after you assign a value to lastX.

Comment: Just added return true and it is still giving me the same error

Comment: i upvoted, maybe someone else can help. I have no other troubleshooting ideas. sry